# Regular expression not working in pywinauto unless I give full text

Tags: python, regex, pywinauto

Here is the code snippet that I am using:

```
browserWin = application.Application()
browserWin.Start(<FirefoxPath>)
# This starts the Firefox browser. 
browserWin.Window_(title_re="\.* Firefox \.*")
```

If I use the expression: ".* Mozilla Firefox Start Page .*", it works. However, if I only use a partial text, it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Nothing wrong, it is probable that the regex is handled with `re.match` that searches for a match from/at the start of the string only. See https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/5176a9eaf568781a0cb8700dd020ab8753592e61/pywinauto/findwindows.py. You may try `".* Firefox "`.

Comment: Escaped `.` with \ means real dot symbol should be at the start of the text. Just remove \.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov, Indeed it worked after removing the '\' character. I think I had tried that too but may be I'd made some other mistake at that time.

Comment: OK, I've added this as an answer. If it solves your problem you're able to mark it as accepted (gray check box under voting buttons), it works with any amount of reputation for any asker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escaped `.` with "\" means real dot symbol should be at the start of the text. Just remove "\".

Answer (score 0):

See this excerpt from the pywinauto source code:

```
title_regex = re.compile(title_re)
def _title_match(w):
    t = handleprops.text(w)
    if t is not None:
        return title_regex.match(t)
    return False
```

The `return title_regex.match(t)` line means that the regex is passed to the [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) method, so, the regex pattern is anchored at the string start.

To match for a partial match, you need to start the pattern with `.*`: `".* FireFox "`.